# Kubernetes - Anyway to load balance requests to a service running on multiple nodes without an external load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

So running and scaling a deployment running **multiple pods** on a **single node** works nicely, and when exposing the service with a type "nodePort" nicely balances requests to the virtual IP between the multiple pods on that individual node.

I've since added an additional node to my cluster, and when exposing the Service using nodePort and then running pods over 2 nodes, I of course need to specify each host specifically to hit the endpoints running in different pods on different nodes.

I would like to send requests to a single VIP and load balance accross the different nodes. I am running this small cluster on my home network, so my question is, is there anyway to send requests to a single VIP, and load balance across the nodes / pods without using an external load-balancer? E.g., is there some config within kubernetes to handle this?

I tried using a service type load balancer (instead of node port) but this didn't load balance accross nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Keepalived in Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/keepalived-vip/README.md).

> The idea is to expose a Virtual IP (VIP) address per service, outside
>   of the kubernetes cluster. keepalived then uses VRRP to sync this
>   "mapping" in the local network. With 2 or more instance of the pod
>   running in the cluster is possible to provide HA using a single VIP
>   address.

Comment: Thanks for the info, so effectively there is no way to handle this without external functionality, such as keepalived?

Comment: Unfortunately kubernetes itself doesn't have this feature for now (v1.8) . ServiceType `LoadBalancer` is only supported in cloud providers (GCE/AWS/Azure), not bare metal.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, if all your pods in both the nodes are attached to the same clusterIP then all pods will be load balanced between the 2 nodes. ClusterIp service works for you as internal load balancer..