# Kubernetes - Not all pods responding to requests to a single node cluter

Tags: kubernetes

I have a **single node minikube cluster** with **5 pods** of same docker image. I want to make 5 or more requests at same time to this node and want requests to be distributed across pods. But when I make requests equal to or greater than the pods in node, some of the requests fail (**500 internal server error**). I confirmed the request did not reach the pod through their logs so I think that the node could not handle that many requests at same time.

Is there a way I can make parallel requests to a node and have them properly distributed across the pods and buffered in case there are no available pods.

Used [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) tutorial to create my cluster

Used [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#scaling-a-deployment) for scaling using following cmd

```
kubectl scale deployment --replicas=5
```

I am using Python requests lib to request the node ip. For parallel requests I am using multiprocessing pool with 5 processes

```
def fn_to_req_node(string):
     requests.post(http://nodeip:nodeport, data=json.dumps(string), headers=headers)

pool= Pool(processes=5)
pool.apply_async(fn_to_req_node, (string1))
pool.apply_async(fn_to_req_node, (string2))
pool.apply_async(fn_to_req_node, (string3))
pool.apply_async(fn_to_req_node, (string4))
pool.apply_async(fn_to_req_node, (string5))
```

UPDATE : Tried on GCE with external Load balancer but same issue - 500 internal server error for some requests.

Comment: The issue persists even if I dont make excatly concurrent requests, but with some delay in between.

Comment: There is not enough information to investigate the problem. Could you please append to the question your Deployment YAML, Service YAML, Ingress YAML(if exists). Also please add output of the command "kubectl get pods,services,ingress --all-namespaces -o wide" Could you also take a look at IPVS mode of the kube-proxy. In IPtables mode Services distribute traffic to pods randomly, not in RoundRobin way.

Answer (score 0):

How are you exposing the server running on the pods, are you using a load balancer / service ?

If you expose the application using a load balancer, load balancer will take care of distributing requests between pods.

Comment: Thanks. I am using minikube cluster which I believe that loadbalancing across the pods by itself (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732208/kubernetes-anyway-to-load-balance-requests-to-a-service-running-on-multiple-no) . However, I also beleive issue is with loadbalacning but since this should be handled bydefalut, i am confused.

Comment: I guess you need to still create a service for the pods and if you hit the service endpoint, it should load balance the requests.
Which endpoint / IP are you hitting to access the pods ?

Comment: Yes, I am creating a service because otherwise I cant work with it on Google Cloud  think. It is external ip of loadbalancer that I am hitting to. In my local minkube cluster it is the nodeip

Comment: @MuhammadMohibKhan Is this question still an issue?